# How to parse a .csv file with quotation marks in C

Tags: c, string, csv, quotation-marks

Lets say the string im trying to parse reads

> "Smith, John",Data1,Data2,Data3

I could also get lines that read

> Dave, Data1,Data2,Data3

so I have the if statement

line is the line of text `fgets()`'d from the file, but I think that works

The rest I've been struggling with for about an hour or so now. I'm trying to reformat the "Smith, John" so its John Smith, then assign it to recTemp.artist

```
if (line[0] == '\"') {
    //Read the last name, first name",
    char lastTemp[30] = "";
    char firstTemp[30] = "";
    strcpy(lastTemp , strtok(line, ", "));
    strcpy(firstTemp, strtok(NULL, "\","));
    char * t;
    t = strstr(lastTemp, "\"");
    strcpy(t, " ");
    //Concatenate each string assign to the artist value
    strcat(firstTemp, lastTemp);
    strcpy(recTemp.artist, firstTemp);
}
```

I think the error comes from the strstr call or the strcpy right after it, but I'm not sure

Thanks!

Comment: Which error do you mean? You forgot to tell us what you expect and what you get and where your problem is. How are your variables and structs defined?

Comment: `strtok(line, ", ")` As you already found out, the first character is `"`, you should start with second character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

> *"I'm trying to reformat the "Smith, John" so its John Smith"*

Short of using regular expressions to extract the quotations out of the string, I would do the following,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line[100] = "\"Smith,John\",Data1,Data2,Data3";
    // fgets(line, 100, stdin);
    char* name = strtok(line, "\"");
    char *substring2 = strtok(NULL, "\"");
    char* LastName = strtok(name, ",");
    char* FirstName = strtok(NULL, ",");

    char result[100];
    strcpy(result, FirstName);
    strcat(result, ",");
    strcat(result, LastName);
    strcat(result, substring2);
    printf("%s",result);

}
```

which produces the output:

> John,Smith,Data1,Data2,Data3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid altering `line` with `strtok`, you can simply use pointer arithmetic to copy either `"first last"` to `recTemp.artist`, or copy `"name"` in the case where no quotes are present in the first field. It's just another approach you can take that avoids modifying the original string. (and a healthy exercise in using pointers)

In the case where quotes are present, you can set a pointer (`p`) to `line + 1` and use `strstr` to find the substring `"\","` setting an end pointer (`endptr`) to the closing quote. You can then call `strchar` on `p` with `','` to locate the comma between `last, first` and set another pointer to advance to the beginning of the first name (`firstp`). Once you have `firstp` pointing to the beginning of the first name, you can just `memcpy` the first name to `recTemp.artist`, add a `space`, and then copy the last name, nul-terminating following that.

In the case of no quote, you need only use `strchr` to locate the `','` field-separator and call `memcpy` and then nul-terminate.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char artist[64];
} rec_t;

int main (void) {
#ifndef NOQUOTE    
    char line[] = "\"Smith, John\",Data1,Data2,Data3";
#else
    char line[] = "Dave,Data1,Data2,Data3";
#endif
    rec_t recTemp;

    if (*line == '\"') {    /* if double-quotes are present */
        char *p = line + 1, *endptr, *sep;    /* ptr, endptr & sep */
        if (!(endptr = strstr (p, "\","))) {  /* find close quote, validate */
            fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
            /* handle error as needed, e.g. */
            return 1;
        }

        if ((sep = strchr (p, ','))) {        /* locate ',' in last, first */
            char *firstp = sep + 1;           /* set firstp to next char */
            while (*firstp && *firstp == ' ') /* skip any leading spaces */
                firstp++;
            memcpy (recTemp.artist, firstp, endptr - firstp); /* copy first */
            endptr = recTemp.artist + (endptr-firstp);  /* set endptr after */
            *endptr++ = ' ';                  /* add a space */
            memcpy (endptr, p, sep - p);      /* copy last */
            *(endptr + (sep - p)) = 0;        /* nul-terminate */
        }
    }
    else {  /* otherwise - name without quotes */
        char *sep = strchr (line, ',');       /* find field seperator */
        if (!sep) {
            fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
            /* handle error as needed, e.g. */
            return 1;
        }
        memcpy (recTemp.artist, line, (sep - line));  /* copy name */
        *(recTemp.artist + (sep - line)) = 0; /* nul-terminate */
    }

    printf ("recTemp.artist: '%s'\n", recTemp.artist);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rectmp
recTemp.artist: 'John Smith'
```

Unquoted name case compiled with `-DNOQUOTE`:

```
$ ./bin/rectmpnq
recTemp.artist: 'Dave'
```

Whether you use `strtok` or walk a few pointers down `line`, both are fine. If you want to preserve `line` unmodified, then either make a copy before operating on the copy with `strtok`, or just use pointer arithmetic. You can dump the assembly generated on both methods to see whether your compiler provides an optimization advantage between the methods. The difference would be negligible in the grand scheme of things.